# Azure Website Pass Public IP Address to Payment Gateway

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, payment-gateway, opayo

I am trying to implement SagePay payment gateway into a Windows Azure website.

I keep recieivng the error "Information Received from an Invalid IP Address".  My guess is the server IP address is being passed as specified as the [LOCAL_ADDR] in the server variables.

Is there a way of forcing the public IP address to be passed to the external gateway?   The commerce site is built using ASP.NET MVC3.

Many Thanks
Matt

Comment: I know it's a long shot, but did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: user2426431, any fixes for this?

Answer (score 0):

The IP Address that you see to use for your A records is not the outgoing IP Address used by Azure Websites. Hence why SagePay does not accept transactions from the website because it is an invalid IP Address.

Instead there are 4 IP Addresses that you need to add, and those 4 IP Addresses depend on what Scale Unit your site uses. 
The scale unit for your site can be found from the FTP Host Name for your Azure website. For example: ftp://waws-prod-blu-011.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net  - the scale unit is 'waws-prod-blu-011'

I then put that into Google, and a couple of azure maintenance articles came up. Scroll the article to you see your region, and then your scale unit and there are the 4 IP Addresses you need.

Please refer to [this azure maintenance article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/fd53afb7-14b8-41ca-bfcb-305bdeea413e/maintenance-notice-upcoming-changes-to-increase-capacity-for-outbound-network-calls?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) for more information.